# What type of soft top is this?

Tags: jeep, wrangler, soft-top

So I bought this abandoned 1999 jeep wrangler SE/TJ that was sitting for 6 years. the soft top is very worn but I want to get an identical one cuz I like the style of it, but I can't seem to find one as I don't know what this would be called. does anyone else know?

[image: rear view of soft top]
[image: Side view of soft top]

Also, I'm pretty sure there is supposed to be a frame for the doors, so there's a seal, if this is true, where can I get some cuz I don't think they were on the jeep when I got it. If not, how do I properly install the top, cuz there's a clear gap between the door and top

Comment: If this has been sitting for years I'd suggest you focus on the mechanical aspects, making sure it's sound before you invest money on the cosmetics.

Comment: Pshaw, @GdD! It's all about the show!

Comment: @GdD i am very aware, i just wanted to know for future reference

Comment: That's good @ZacharyCross, and I'm glad you're thinking that way. I've seen people waste a lot of money on cosmetic upgrades for cars that were mechanically unsound and it's never come out well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is typically called a "bikini" top. There's different models and styles, but this name usually encompasses what you're looking for ... I did a quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wrangler+bikini+top&oq=wrangler+bikini+top) and it showed quite a few different options.